# Hide hover element when cursor not over parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple `inline-block` elements on my project.

Each of these elements have a hidden "tooltip" which shows when you hover over them.

But this tooltip won't hide if cursor over it so, to see the tooltip of another element below you have first to move cursor away and back which is not much user friendly.

I have made an snippet to better show my problem. What I want is to hide the `hover-element` as soon as cursor not over red boxes.

I don't think there's a way with just CSS so any JavaScript/jQuery solution is very welcome.

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.hover-element {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 350px;
  height: 175px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -175px;
  top: 25px;
  display: none;
}

li:hover .hover-element {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Will users need to interact with the tooltip content? Wondering would click to reveal tooltip be more user friendly than hover in your case?

Comment: Nope. no interaction. that's why I used hover. ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `visibility: hidden` property on the `.hover-element` on hover.

```css
li {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  height:25px;
  margin-right:10px;
  position:relative;
}
.hover-element {
  position: absolute;
  background-color:yellow;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 350px;
  height: 175px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -175px;
  top:25px;
  display:none;
}
li:hover .hover-element {
  display:block;
}
.hover-element:hover {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ty. I am not thinking strike today. I should have solve it myself :) Will give you the credit in 4 more minutes as your answer was the first

Answer (score 2):

```
.hover-element {    
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Ty. this works also but have to give the "right answer" to first post.

Comment: solutions are different, but it's up to you

Answer (score 0):

```css
li {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  height:25px;
  margin-right:10px;
  position:relative;
}
.hover-element {
  position: absolute;
  background-color:yellow;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 350px;
  height: 175px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -175px;
  top:25px;
  display:none;
}
li:hover .hover-element {
  display:block;
}
li .hover-element:hover {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="hover-element"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ty. this works also but have to give the "right answer" to first post.

Comment: Fine. I got little late